# PsiFile not parsed for file error does not let me open Project Structure in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I started getting this error after I imported a library (extendedCalendarView)  into Android Studio. It happens when I try to open Project Structure from File menu, or 'Open Module Settings'.

Here's the full error details:
PsiFile not parsed for file C:/leandro/lagoonapps/RoutePlanner/RoutePlanner/build.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.: PsiFile not parsed for file C:/leandro/lagoonapps/RoutePlanner/RoutePlanner/build.gradle. Wait until onPsiFileAvailable() is called.

My build.gradle at project level remains untouched from the first day.
The modules' gradle file was only updated to reflect the sdk version

The app still compiles correctly but the library classes are not to be found at run time:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lagoonapps.routeplanner/com.lagoonapps.routeplanner.MainAct}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I've the same error while importing a new project in IntelliJ. When I select the gradle file and choose Import, a new window opens to select the modules to be imported. When clicked OK, nothing happens and in the log file, this is logged. `"PsiFile not parsed for build.gradle"`. I'm using IDEA 15.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and when I cleared the project files it wouldn't even allow me to re-import the project.

How I fixed it: Close Android Studio/IntelliJ, clear your project files, and go into your top-level `settings.gradle` where you comment all your module includes. If you now try to open the project, it should just show the top-level module being used, but with the folder structure of your child modules there. Now go into your `settings.gradle` and uncomment the includes. Do a gradle sync and everything should be back in its original place.

I know this is just treating the symptoms, but it did get me a working project again.